# listview item showing only one textview data-android

Tags: android, listview

i have created a listview which has 1 image, and 2 texts.
but in the output , the listview is showing only second textview data. first textview is blank.

here is my listview's single item layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff">

<!-- icon -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />

<!-- title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_counter"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:background="@drawable/counter"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- counter -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrow"/>
```

and here is data model code:

```
    public class DataModel {

    String name;
    String counter;

    public DataModel(String name,String counter ) {
        this.name=name;
        this.counter=counter;
    }

    public String getName() { return name;}

    public String getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

here is the CustomAdapter.java

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCounter;
        ImageView icon;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.category_list, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            viewHolder.txtCounter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_counter);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
        viewHolder.txtCounter.setText(dataModel.getCounter());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById();
    clickListeners();


    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.caregoryList);

    dataModels= new ArrayList<>();


    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Banana Bread", " 9"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Cupcake", "9"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Donut","9"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Eclair", "9"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Froyo", "0"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Gingerbread", "0"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Honeycomb","1"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Ice Cream Sandwich", "1"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Jelly Bean", "2"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Kitkat", "3"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("Lollipop","4"));



    adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            DataModel dataModel= dataModels.get(position);
          Snackbar.make(view, dataModel.getName()+"\n"+dataModel.getName()+" API: "+dataModel.getCounter(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("No action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

so, after running this code, listview is displaying only second counter text. first textview is displaing as blank.

Comment: The `layout_width` of your first textview is `0dp`

Comment: but i have added layout_weight

Comment: is your problem solved yet?

Comment: Not  yet...@ tahsinRupam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's almost no problem in your xml and code for this manner, you're just missing the textColor attribute. The text is default white (probably it's related to the theme you've selected). 
Just add to the textView item_title a color for example :

```
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
```

and you'll see the text.

Comment: @Dus- Thank you so much... :D

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your XML,copy and paste it and try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff">

<!-- icon -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    />

<!-- title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="hello"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_counter"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:background="@drawable/counter"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- counter -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrow"/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: @Androidss- still its not showing first textview data